# How to modify the .coffee file and make it work in the interactive mode

Tags: coffeescript

I download a coffeescript project on github and I hope to modify the source code, but when i add some code in some .coffee files, nothing changes(i run the project in the interactive mode(RELP), I've already setup the Nodejs and coffee environment). I'm wondering how to modify the source code and run it just like python. Do i need to compile or something? Thanks so much.

Comment: have you used `cake build`? Your `coffee` should then be a new one.